# Shell Command for extracting number

Tags: shell, bash

I have a string as
echo "abc.${build-id}" >> new.txt
Now, in this build-id i want to extract build number.
Please help me to know the regex for and command''
${build-id} is like abc_001 and i need to extract 001

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's easy enough with:

```
$ text=abc_001
$ echo ${text##*_}
001
```

Look into [string manipulation](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html), it's remarkably useful.

Answer (score 0):

One line solution

```
echo ${build-id} | cut -d'_' -f2
```